# Sugar daddy wants my online banking login info to make deposits — is it a scam?

Tags: scams, online-banking, sugar-daddy

Someone is offering to pay me in a sort of sugar daddy/sugar baby arrangement. They want to make online deposits to me, and they're asking me for my online banking username and password. Is that information alone enough for them to be able to take my money out of my account, or am I safe?

Comment: I never saw a "Is this a scam ..." question on here where the answer was No!

Comment: @Daniel On Meta: [Have there been any “Is this a scam?” questions that the answer was “No”?](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2542/10997)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79983/discussion-on-question-by-anonymous-am-i-being-scammed-by-this-rich-person).  This means no further comments should be posted here. Go to chat if you wish to comment or offer your opinion/advice.

Comment: Ask them to give you *their* account, login name and password first, and transfer some money to your account.

Answer (score 301, accepted):

> they're asking me for my online banking username and password. is that
>   information alone enough for them to be able to take my money out of
>   my account, or am i safe?

They don't need that information to deposit funds to your account, and having that information will allow them to take money out of your account. You are being set up to be robbed. In the fine print of the terms of service with your bank you probably agreed *not to give your password to anyone else*, so if your account gets emptied the bank may not be very sympathetic.

Do not give your bank password to anyone, and be extremely suspicious of anyone who asks for it.

Comment: I would add: "call the police on anyone who asks your bank password"

Comment: @Daniel: "Call the police" is usually a bad idea. Even if you're totally innocent of whatever scam is going on, your name is now connected to it. And in OP's case, being that it's a "sugar daddy" situation, they might be involved in sex work, in which case police awareness of them is almost certainly a serious problem.

Comment: If you give your credentials to someone, as far as the bank is concerned, that someone **IS YOU**. So yeah, they can then *deposit* in your account. They can also withdraw everything, order cheques, transfer money out, and if your online banking is linked to your credit card then they can fill it up with a cash advance transfer and disappear before you get to say "oh". Your banking credentials are more private than your sex life. They're between you and the bank's servers - NOT EVEN BANK EMPLOYEES KNOW YOUR CREDENTIALS. The ONLY reason anyone could ask for your creds, is to screw you over.

Comment: @Daniel Terrible idea. What do you think the police are going to do for vaguely attempted online crime? Asking for a password is not illegal. You're going to have to hustle your ass off to get the FBI involved. Don't waste their time and yours.

Comment: Don't call "911" emergency, but definitely get connected to law enforcement.  If you're not educated enough to know whether something is a scam, law enforcement can point to resources that helps you.  "Call the police" is not always a 911 emergency call.

Comment: @R. That's what the scammers are counting on. If no one reports them, they'll never get caught. If enough do, they will be.

Comment: Another "proverb" that applies here.  "If it sounds too good to be true, it usually is."  A stranger offering you money for no apparently good reason other than supposed philanthropy is a classic example of this.

Comment: @dgnuff a sugar daddy/sugar baby arrangement is definitely not philanthropy, and plenty of people do engage in it.

Comment: @coinbird Having reported cyber-crime to the FBI myself and discussed it with an investigating officer, my understanding is that the FBI will happily take the information and keep a record of it. They will never tell you if or when or how they investigate, but that's no reason not to report. You definitely don't have to "hustle your ass off" in any way at all. One of the benefits of reporting is that it adds to the information available for investigations and prosecutions, even if one report doesn't result in prosecution, it will help down the road.

Comment: @R.. If  the police knowing you might be considered a sex worker or not will is a bad thing depends on the legal jurisdiction a person is living in. In some countries such as America prostitution is illegal in others it's legal and regulated.

Comment: at least in my Country (Germany) you need a TAN for any action involves money transfer or anything. So only login data alone can't do much harm. Of course, he can see every transaction but he still need a TAN for every action he wanna make.

Comment: @undefined I'm not familiar with Germany, but I know I can transfer money without any additional authorization from my U.S. bank accounts simply by logging in to my online account. Granted, there are a few access controls in addition to just username/password. But, once you're logged in, ACH transfers are pretty easy to do.

Comment: @reirab wow I didn't know US bank accounts are that insecure. That's surprisingly. If I fill out the form for a transfer, click on send, I get a message on my mobile phone with a number I have to enter at the form in order to complete the transfer. Without that random number it's not possible to make any transfer of money

Comment: @undefined: How do you write a check in Germany? Seems like it'd be a much more onerous process if one first had to contact the bank to get an authorization number.

Comment: @cHao In Germany, we don't write checks (anymore) :-) But yes, in online banking, a one-time-pad (TAN, "Transaktionsnummer", "transaction number") must always be provided; used to be printed lists sent to you via mail by the bank, now mostly either "mobile" sent on demand as text message or even "ChipTAN" requiring physical access to the account's debit (chip-)card and a special handheld device (card reader) which calculates the TAN from the transaction details and the secret stored inside the card's chip. The latter is as secure as one can get technically (with "only" 6-digit TANs).

Comment: @undefined Oh, lots of U.S. banks use 2FA just to get into the account, so it's not so much a matter of it being less secure, as a matter of that level of security being required to log in in the first place, rather than only for ACH transfers. Many banks do give you the option to 'remember' a particular device/browser combo, though, in which case it won't do the code every time. However, if I (or someone else) attempts to log in to my bank account from a different location/computer/browser, it sends a message like the one you describe with a code to allow the login.

Comment: @reirab The important point with the TAN protocol is that you have to authenticate each transaction separately (with a specific four digit code that is valid only a single time)

Comment: @VolkerSiegel I'm just not sure _why_ that's important. It sounds like the only purpose that serves is to allow you to perform non-transaction account functions without the 2FA.

Comment: @reirab in most modern TAN-systems the details (amount, receiving account number) of the transaction you are about to authorize are transmitted back to you over a second (hopefully independent) channel - in the SMS containing the TAN or on your TAN-generator. So you can check whether the transaction has been tampered with by a man-in-the-middle.

Answer (score 74):

In addition to the simpler "it's a scam" answers, part of the sugar daddy arrangement is control. If the sugar daddy doesn't get what he wants, he should have control of the sugar baby account to take back his money or re-assert control. This ranges from controlling the bank accounts to having control of credit cards or paying rent. If he isn't kept happy, he has an immediate ability to terminate access to housing, transport, and money.

Conceivably the sugar daddy could simply set up access to one of his accounts for you, but that weakens his level of control as compared to controlling your accounts. Him cutting you off from your money puts the power in his hands.

Another aspect of control is also surveillance. If the sugar arrangement is exclusive the daddy will want to see accounts to make sure it is exclusive.

To be clear - I think answers that this is simply a scam to steal your money are more likely. However there is an additional insidious angle with the sugar daddy arrangement.

Comment: +1 This is of course the real reason (or concern). Going into a sugar babe relation _doesn't_ just mean getting money for nothing.

Comment: Of course this means that there's no reason OP can't create a dummy account that she does give to the Sugar Daddy. This would limit the exposure to potential losses, though getting money out may be difficult without raising suspicion or giving away the other account info. It'd probably be best to use this account via like a debit card, then extract cash from ATMs or make purchases directly. That way the Daddy can't get access to the account information of any direct transfers.

Comment: Even if you use a dummy account, most banks strictly forbid giving your login credentials to anyone, even your wife. They can and will freeze access, deny liability and may even take legal action if something happens and they find out you shared your password.

Comment: @NateDiamond You're getting into the realm of how a sugar babe can protect her own interest and independence while in an inherently dependent relationship. The nature of the work is such that a sufficiently controlling sugar daddy would be observing transactions and noting things like transfers to cash or deposits to an IRA. I'm sure that the sugar relationships fall on a spectrum of hands-off to very hands-on (excuse the pun). I think in OPs case we can safely assume that this is one with a strong element of control and any attempt to circumvent that control would be frowned on.

Comment: In addition to potentially "cutting you off", it's also about surveillance. Even if he never threatens to cut you off, every purchasing decision you make is now under his review.

Comment: Once the ask for username/password has happened all bets are off as to the validity of anything else this person says or implies.  I would assume they are looking to only steal cash and not get into any kind of relationship at all.

Comment: @James I think the point here is that a "relationship" with that level of power imbalance is easily capable of easily being just as bad *or worse* than just plain financial theft. Theft happens and then you shut the gates - it's a one-time event - abuse of life-controlling leverage in a relationship can actively change a life for decades before it's stopped and can wreak lasting psychological damage that a theft can never hope to cause.

Comment: @Freiheit in the end, what OP is trying to do comes with all the perils of scamming-a-scammer :)

Answer (score 16):

OF COURSE it is a scam  --- DO NOT give ANYONE your banking login

-- to pay money TO you,  all they need is  your bank account number (8 digits) and sort code (6 digits) - NOTHING ELSE.

If he's asking for your login,  he wants to STEAL your money.

As others said  -   stay away / report to police.

Good luck

Comment: Note that the structure and length of account details is not standard internationally (there is a standard format for international transfers, but it's not the one you describe), and the question doesn't say what country this is in. Other than that, this doesn't really add anything not already said in other answers. If you're new to the format of this site, you might want to take the [tour].

Comment: Not only are account numbers not internationally standard, they're not even necessarily standard between 2 banks in the same country. Account number lengths vary from bank to bank here in the U.S. Small, local banks tend to have shorter account numbers, while very large national banks have much longer ones.

Comment: @reirab: Yes and no.  My credit union account is 4 digits when I visit in person, everywhere else it needs 8 leading zeros :-)

Comment: @reirab Good point. Even in the UK, Building Societies traditionally use "roll numbers" and other internal schemes; for external transfers, you have to specify that as the payment reference against a generic account number for the entire society (like paying a bill).

Comment: @jamesqf 8 digits is what I was thinking of as an example of 'short.' ;) My accounts with large U.S. banks are much longer than that, while my accounts with local banks are just 8. Also, routing codes are 9 digits here, not the 6 mentioned in the answer.

Answer (score 14):

Criminals seek people who want to give or sell their bank accounts so that they can use the accounts for money laundering. One such group are students who are known to sell their accounts on after they graduate. Once the criminal has a bank account they can insert money into the financial system and make it appear legitimate.

Don't do it, report it to the bank immediately.

Comment: Report what to the bank? "A guy asked for my password" That's not illegal. The bank will say "Ok, don't give it to him..."

Comment: @coinbird A friend of mine used to work in some sort of fraud prevention team at a large bank. They would have loved to receive any sort of identifying information pertaining to the scammer.

Comment: @BooleanCheese That's a nice anecdote, but they absolutely won't do anything with the fake name and email address this guy gave her. And it being based on some low level phishing? Waste of everyone's time.

Comment: @coinbird Fake names and fake email addresses are still information that could be useful. They may use the same fake info in multiple scams, which ties them to multiple crimes. That being said, I wouldn't report them here if OP is involved in sex work actively and this wasn't just some random proposition.

Comment: @coinbird it is surely a fake name, but it's a real e-mail address that can be used to communicate with the person.  This could be useful for any of a number of reasons, for example, it could be used to extract other information that could lead to an arrest and conviction.

Answer (score 2):

First, you really need to explain more about this "sort of sugar daddy/sugar baby arrangement".  Have you signed up for one of the sites that set up such arrangements?  Do you know the person?  Negotiated details of your "arrangement"?  Given them a taste of the "sugar"?  If not, then why would you think Daddy is going to be interested in paying you (yet).

Second, and the smoking gun that this is a scam, you don't need the bank account password to make deposits, just the account number.  It's possible that a potential sugar daddy might want to pay via bank transfer, just the account number.

Comment: Unforunately even the account number is not secure.

Comment: More likely, someone actually engaging in such behavior - particularly in places where it's not legal - would use cash rather than a bank transfer. Bank transfers are 100% traceable and make great evidence at a trial. Cash is much more of a pain to track (and much less likely to raise suspicion for the person doing the paying... though making periodic large cash deposits might raise suspicion for the person receiving the payments, particularly if they are of the young age most common in arrangements of this nature.)

Comment: @reirab: We don't know that the OP is in a place where it's not legal.  Direct deposits are quite common, after all.  My consulting fees (and salary back in the day) are paid that way, I pay my taxes to the government that way, my credit card & other bills, horse expenses to my friend...  Had I any intention of being a sugar daddy, I'm sure I would handle things through direct deposit.

Comment: @jamesqf Yes, nearly all of my deposits and expenses work that way, too. But, then, I'm not doing anything questionable or illegal.

Comment: @EJP why would an IBAN be dangerous to give? (it is not at least in France)

Comment: @WoJ It may vary location, but in principle giving bank details plus the holder's name is enough for fraudsters to take actions causing money to be taken out of the account  (at least temporarily). This is why checking bank statements is important. https://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/uknews/1574781/Jeremy-Clarkson-eats-his-words-over-ID-theft.html

Comment: @origimbo direct debit in France requires your signature in order to be processed. The signature can be forged of course, this is why it is always the bank fault when there is a draft you do not agree with. Some banks will allow DD without your signature, again taking the risk. You are correct that checking your account for this is the way to go (or actually - the DD drawers, one usually has this in their online account).

Comment: @origimbo (cont'd)  In the same vein you could get payments to your account which may not be legal and you could have problems with them (tax, money laundering, ...) if you do not check. The thing is that you always have the possibility to dispute the line and you are always right, except if the bank proves that you are not.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I have seen "legitimate" online services that verify your account details via your username and password:

[Online money management applications: Do you trust Mint.com or Quicken Online, or other personal finance tools online?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/99/online-money-management-applications-do-you-trust-mint-com-or-quicken-online-o)

This is a terrible idea and you shouldn't do it, but it does make it possible that your correspondent isn't scamming you.

(There is, of course, still a decent chance that he is scamming you after all. Certainly he could use that information to do so. But it's not the *only possible* explanation.)

Comment: Yes, it is the only possible explanation. There is **no chance** this is legitimate. Any glimmer of hope you provide to a potential scammee could be enough to make them give up on their doubts. A hard line must be drawn against all fraudulent activity, of which this is one. Yes, there is a Prince of Wales, but he won't email me about Her Majesty's Royal Lottery Winnings, so there's no point pretending such a contact '*might*' be legitimate. This falls into the same camp.

Comment: They have systems that make it hard (but not impossible) for people to see the information you enter, including their own employees. Most websites that you login to cannot see your passwords (which is why you have to "reset" them if you forget them). Giving your password to such a system is **way** different than giving it to some individual person.

Comment: @Clay07g That is not true. Any service that logs into another service for you needs the password in plain text or encrypted in a way that is reversible back to plain text. If you give your online banking login credentials to some such service, you might be in violation of the bank's terms of use and they surely will deny any liability in case of misuse. **Do not give away your online banking login credentials ever.**

Comment: Very true answer. Unfortunately, recently a number of services have appeared that handle money for you by asking for your bank account credentials, and they are actually legitimate businesses (doing their business in a horrible, horrible way that teaches people all the wrong things). This scam and others like it might be riding on that wave. Not that us security experts hadn't predicted this would happen.

Comment: It'd be nice if banks providing online services supported OAuth or something like it.  Unfortunately, it seems most don't (at least in the US). The only common way i've seen of letting anyone else access your account is to give them your login info.

Comment: It's worth noting that, in the UK, there is now a standard way for such applications to access your data without you giving away your login credentials, branded as ["Open Banking"](https://www.openbanking.org.uk/). Without this in place, I would not want a third party to access my accounts, so I agree, **do not give away your online banking credentials ever**, however much convenient functionality is offered in return.

Comment: The premise of this answer is correct (there are sties that require your banking credentials), but the conclusion is incorrect ("it does make it possible that your correspondent isn't scamming you"). The last sentence of the comment by @Clay07g explains why.

Comment: @tobiv All encryption is technically reversible, if you have the proper keys. If you *don't* have these keys (99% of employees that work at the company), it takes **several billion years to decrypt** with a normal computer. Plaintext password storage is almost never used nowadays.