# Online Sugar Daddy and Bitcoin

Tags: scams, cryptocurrency, sugar-daddy

I met a guy through Snapchat and he says he’s a sugar daddy. He claims he’ll pay me an allowance weekly through Cash App. But before he starts giving me an allowance he wants me to download and create an account on this Bitcoin app. I told him I did but now he wants the login information I created. Is this a scam? He’s sent me pictures of himself through Snapchat and even posts on his story. I’m having a hard time determining if this is real or not. I’ve had scammers message me and I’ve read things online, but this seems different. Please help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sugar daddy wants my online banking login info to make deposits — is it a scam?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/97274/sugar-daddy-wants-my-online-banking-login-info-to-make-deposits-is-it-a-scam)

Comment: Search for Sugar Daddy on this website. Every single time it turned out to be a scam. Don't fall for this crap. Treat "Sugar Daddies" like you would a deposed "Nigerian Prince" The Bitcoin aspect increases the chance of it being a scam by approximately 8 gazillion percent.

Comment: Yes.  Every "sugar daddy" scheme that doesn't involve you having sex with the guy is a scam.

Comment: What @jamesqf said.  A sugar daddy is **not** someone who gives you money for no reason.  **There is a reason.**  If he's not asking for sex, it's *definitely* a scam.  If he *is* asking for sex, it may still be a scam on top of that, so be careful.

Answer (score 5):

It’s not different than before. This is a scam. Everything he has told you is a lie. There essentially is no such thing as an online sugar daddy. It is all a scam.

Don’t give him your login information for anything, and stop all communication with him.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this isindicitive of a scam. I'd expect your "sugar daddy" to use your account for dodgey transactions. Creating accounts on C
crypto platforms is not easy as you need to verify a matching NI Number and government ID, so stealing legitimate accounts is profitable.